# Getting an error like this and unable to get the FCM token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

*This is the Error Occurred*.FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).
**Please help me to add service worker file**.**I am not getting FCM token soon after getting permission from the user**

**I am unable to get the fcm token , I have already added the code to get permission from the user soon after accepting the permission from the user it returns that error, and I don't know where should I add my service worker file and should I add that in the way I have added? any help will be appreciated**

this is my code in firebase.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function(){
            console.log("GRANTED");
            console.log(messaging.getToken());
            return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(function(token){
            console.log(token);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('Error Occurred.' + err)
        });
```

Comment: Why do we need the image? The image just takes up Mobile user's precious data (And I have been one for quite a while and don't appreciate finding images in questions when unneeded)

Comment: I just wanted to know where should I add service worker file in my project.Any help will be appreciated,since i am new to this unable to find route to add firebase-messaging-sw.js

Comment: **Technically** the location doesn't matter in the eyes of the software unless they are split between server and client. As long as it can path there the physical location is unimportant but if it needs to contact something to make a path then it matters. So just depends on do you need it on a separate hardware or the same?

Comment: But if you want to know the location it might be a good idea to put that in the question and bold it to show importance

Comment: same ,and I am not getting FCM token after getting permission from the user,in order to show him the push notification

Comment: There we go! Making it clear is extremely useful for us to pinpoint errors. I'll give you a vote up since my only issue is the image but the rest of this question seems okay to me

Comment: I just wanted to show the structure that's why I have posted the image too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222697/discussion-between-nino-c-philip-and-the-grand-j).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in the **server** root. It's not really important where you put it in the **source** folder.